# Twitter scripts fail in IE9 when running as a Facebook app (i.e. within an iFrame)

Tags: facebook, twitter, internet-explorer-9

We have a Facebook app that includes web intents integration to award bonus points when users tweet about their performance. The app runs with no problem in all browsers outside of Facebook and in all browsers except IE9 when run within Facebook. The issue seems to stem from the way Facebook runs the code within an iframe.

The specific error we are seeing occurs during page load in hubclient.js (line 7): Unable to get value of the property insertBefore.

The code is integrated into our app based on https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents/events

In the document head we have the following script to setup the twitter platform api:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  window.twttr = (function (d,s,id) {
    var t, js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return; js=d.createElement(s); js.id=id;
    js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    return window.twttr || (t = { _e: [], ready: function(f){ t._e.push(f) } });
  }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));
</script>
```

We were then using a simple Follow button within the document body

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/clearcreativity" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false">Follow</a>
```

Finally, we have event bindings that are wrapped in a $(document).ready() block:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    twttr.ready(function (twttr) {
    twttr.events.bind('tweet', function(event) {
            //Notify and potentially give credit for a tweet
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: please provide more information other then its a FB app running web intents. There are no known issues with these two attributes alone. Code usually goes a long way around here.

Comment: I changed our app code so that platform.twitter.com/widgets.js was loaded synchronously at the end of the doc body and also modified our internal event bindings to the intents so they were in a query $(document).ready. This fixed the issue for us with no apparent loss in functionality.

Comment: ok cool.. write that into an answer and accept it when you can

Comment: Will do - apparently have to wait for 6 hours to self answer

Answer (score 0):

Having gone around on this issue a number of times trying different resolution options, it seems to be related to the async loading of the platform scripts when running within an iframe. To resolve this issue we simply moved the load of the platform api to be a synchronous call at the end of the page load:

```
    <script src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
<body>
```

And of course, made sure that all references to twttr within our code were wrapped in a

```
$(document).ready();
```